# Akka application - can't exit the application after shutting down actor system - how to find what is still alive?

Tags: scala, akka, kill

I'm working on a piece of code I'm not too too close to. It uses several inhouse built libraries and I suspect there is a thread pool or netty connection open somewhere - how can I find what's on the heap/stack that's causing the akka app to not shut down correctly?

I've thrown errors, called System.exit(1) and context.system.shutdown to try to get out of the process but nada.

We're writing in scala - probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Try using jconsole and look at the Threads tab before and after you call system.shutdown, see what's hanging around.

Comment: Looks like it's netty. Guess I have to manually clean up the workers on shutdown.